# "What is the best version of Unity for developing Hololens app using MRTK?"

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I begin in creating apps for Hololens.
I plan to use Unity and MRTK.

What is currently the best version of Unity for developing Hololens app using MRTK?

Comment: Latest stable release of the MRTK is `HoloToolkit 2017.4.3.0` which states `The recommended Editor version is 2017.4 LTS (Long Term Support)`

Comment: If you start a fresh new project, I'd strongly recommend using MRTK **v2** as there are breaking API changes. v2 is in release candidate state quite a while and is expected to be final in July 2019, s. [Roadmap](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Contributing/Roadmap.html). This works with 2018.4 LTS and 2019.1. See [MRTK Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases)

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the current version the MRTK is using by inspecting the [Project Version file.](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt)

At the time of writing the version of Unity is: 2018.4.1f1

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile with the newer MRTK 2.3, they recommend 2018.4 onward.

I'm currently using 2019.2.21f1 with MRTK 2.3.

In my recommendation if you go for a Hololens 1 or Hololens 2 use 2019.1.xx or later with the newest MRTK.